# Flutter "Null check operator used on a null value"

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

Using scrollview, I created a system that retrieves the first 10 users from the database and returns the remaining users in the scroll. The last user will be null at first, and then the value will be assigned. I think I got an error because the method is null at the first time.

UPDATE:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //build metodu tetiklendikten sonra gelicek (context belli olduktan sorna)
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {

      getUser(_sonUser!); <---------------- ERROR!!
      
      print("SCHEDULERBİNDİNG ÇALIŞTI");
    });
    _scrollController.addListener((() {
      (_scrollController.offset >= _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent &&
              !_scrollController.position.outOfRange)
          ? getUser(_sonUser!) // En Altta

          : (_scrollController.offset <=
                      _scrollController.position.minScrollExtent &&
                  !_scrollController.position.outOfRange)
              ? print("En Üstte")
              : print("scroll ediliyor");
    }));
  }
```

metod is

```
getUser(User1 sonUser) async {
    final _usermodel = Provider.of<UserModel>(context, listen: false);

    if (!_dahaVarmi) {
      print("ELEMAN KALMADI MK");
      return;
    }
    if (_yukleniyor) {
      return;
    }
    setState(() {
      _yukleniyor = true;
    });
    sonUser = _kullanicilarListesi!.last;
    List<User1> users = await _usermodel.getUsersWithPagination(
        sonUser, _getirilecekElemanCount);
    if (_kullanicilarListesi == null) {
      _kullanicilarListesi = [];
      _kullanicilarListesi!.addAll(users);
    } else {
      _kullanicilarListesi!.addAll(users);
    }
    if (users.length < _getirilecekElemanCount) {
      _dahaVarmi = false;
    }
    for (var element in querySnapshot.docs) {
      User1 tekUser = User1.fromMap(element.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
      _kullanicilarListesi!.add(tekUser);
      debugPrint("Getirelen usr  name  ==> ${tekUser.userName}");
    }*/

    sonUser = _kullanicilarListesi!.last;
    debugPrint("en son user name ==>  ${sonUser.userName}");

    setState(() {
      _yukleniyor = false;
    });
  }
```

database metod

```
 @override
  Future<List<User1>> getUsersWithPagination(
      User1? lastgetUser, int getirilecekElemanSayisi) async {
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot;
    List<User1> _tumKullanicilar = [];
    debugPrint("ilk kullanıcılar getriliyor");
    if (lastgetUser == null) {
      debugPrint("ilk kullanıcılar getriliyor");
      //firestore ilk 10 tane elemanı vericek ve ordby sayesinde Username i a dan z dizicek
      querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("users")
          .orderBy("userName")
          .limit(getirilecekElemanSayisi)
          .get();
    } else {
      debugPrint("sonrakiler getiriliyor");
      querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("users")
          .orderBy("userName")
          .startAfter([lastgetUser.userName])
          .limit(getirilecekElemanSayisi)
          .get();
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(
        seconds: 1,
      ));
    }
    for (var element in querySnapshot.docs) {
      User1 tekUser = User1.fromMap(element.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
      _tumKullanicilar.add(tekUser);
      debugPrint("Getirelen usr  name  ==> ${tekUser.userName}");
    }

    return _tumKullanicilar;
  }
```

ERORR message

> Exception caught by scheduler library ═════════════════════════════════
> The following _CastError was thrown during a scheduler callback:
> Null check operator used on a null value
>
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
> #0      _KullanicilarPAgeState.initState.
> kullanicilar.dart:39
> #1      SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
> binding.dart:1175
> #2      SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
> binding.dart:1113
> #3      SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame
> binding.dart:1015
> #4      _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:148:13)
> #5      PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:318:5)
> #6      _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)

I checked sonuser in several places, but the error was still the same.(if-else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have logic issue in the code.

Change

```
  getUser(_sonUser!); <---------------- ERROR!!
```

to

```
if(_sonUser!=null){
   getUser(_sonUser!);
}
```

And even change

```
 _scrollController.addListener((() {
      (_scrollController.offset >= _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent &&
              !_scrollController.position.outOfRange)
          ? getUser(_sonUser!) // En Altta

          : (_scrollController.offset <=
                      _scrollController.position.minScrollExtent &&
                  !_scrollController.position.outOfRange)
              ? print("En Üstte")
              : print("scroll ediliyor");
    }));
```

to

```
 _scrollController.addListener((() {
      (_scrollController.offset >= _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent &&
              !_scrollController.position.outOfRange)
          ? _sonUser!=null ? getUser(_sonUser!)  //  add this check as well

          : (_scrollController.offset <=
                      _scrollController.position.minScrollExtent &&
                  !_scrollController.position.outOfRange)
              ? print("En Üstte")
              : print("scroll ediliyor");
    }));
```

Comment: i updated my code same error

Comment: hmm not errror but not working. Actually, the problem is that the _sonUser value is null in the first step and then the first 10 users are returned in the FireBase section, and at the end of this method, the 10th element is assigned to _sonUser.

Answer (score 0):

You are having incorrect condition on checking `null`.

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (_sonUser == null) {//Before _sonUser != null
        print("object");
      } else {
        getUser(_sonUser!);
      }
      // getUser(_sonUser!);
      print("SCHEDULERBİNDİNG ÇALIŞTI");
    });
```

Comment: i updated my code same error